# Excel vba function with specific part of a path as variable

Tags: excel, vba

I have a function in excel that gives hour of last modification using path , only one part of the path changes  exp:

> \c:\xcl\report\sudtrack\20200324\dossier22

the part is `20200324`

i want to do something like that : `function('20200324')` the code will place it in the path

```
path="\\c:\xcl\report\sudtrack\" & 20200324 &"\dossier22"
```

my current code

```
Function End_hour(path As String)

    End_hour = Format(FileDateTime(path), "hh:mm:ss")

End Function
```

Comment: What time does `20200324` represent?  I can see it representing the date 24th March 2020, but not a time - unless it's 20:03:24?

Comment: yes it's a date (folder named with date of creation)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> i want to do something like that : function('20200324') the code will place it in the path

No need to use use a function. You can directly do a `Replace`. Just set up a base string as shown below and do the replace.

```
Option Explicit

Sub Sample()
    Dim myPath As String

    myPath = "\\c:\xcl\report\sudtrack\HOUROFLASTMOD\dossier22"

    MsgBox Replace(myPath, "HOUROFLASTMOD", "20200324")
End Sub
```

**Note**: I have used `HOUROFLASTMOD`. You can change it to whatever string you want.

If you still want to use a function then try this

```
Option Explicit

Sub Sample()
    MsgBox ReturnNewPath("20200324")
End Sub

Function ReturnNewPath(TimeString As String)
    Dim myPath As String
    myPath = "\\c:\xcl\report\sudtrack\HOUROFLASTMOD\dossier22"

    ReturnNewPath = Replace(myPath, "HOUROFLASTMOD", TimeString)
End Function
```